# Reordering boxplots by median using `fct_reorder`

Tags: r, ggplot2, forcats

**Current Code**

```r
box_scottishpolitics_karma <<- ggplot(hedges_scottishpolitics_data,
                                        aes(x=fct_reorder(unique_word, 
                                            utterance_score, median), 
    y=utterance_score)) + 
    geom_boxplot(fill="red", color = "black") +
    scale_y_continuous(trans=scales::pseudo_log_trans(base = 10)) +
    ggtitle("Subreddit: Scottish Politics") +
    xlab("Hedge/Booster") +
    ylab("Karma Score (log10)") +
    coord_flip() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
    geom_boxplot(data=boosters_scottishpolitics_data, fill="lightblue", 
                 color = "black") +
    coord_flip() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

**Current Output**

[image: boxplots, but not sorted by the median values].

I cannot seem to get it to sort the boxplots by their median values.

I have tried using `reorder()` as well as `fct_reorder()`. However, neither of these seem to work. Both reorder and fct_reorder produce the same result.

#### Solution

Since the creation of this post there has been a slight change in data structure. The z-score is now also part of the dataset and must be used to create a plot as well.

```
# Combining the 2 datasets into one
hedges_scottishpolitics_data <- hedges_scottishpolitics_data %>%
    mutate(type = "hedge")
boosters_scottishpolitics_data <<- boosters_scottishpolitics_data %>%
    mutate(type = "booster")
all_scottishpolitics_data <- rbind(hedges_scottishpolitics_data, boosters_scottishpolitics_data)

# Turning 'type' column into factors (for colouring in boxplot)
all_scottishpolitics_data$type <- as.factor(all_scottishpolitics_data$type)
  all_scottishpolitics_data <- all_scottishpolitics_data %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    # add 2 columns, one ordered by median karma score and one ordered by 
    # median z score. (so we can create both boxplots).
    mutate(word_med_order = fct_reorder(unique_word, utterance_score))%>%
    mutate(word_med_order_z = fct_reorder(unique_word, z_score))
  
  # Karma boxplot, now ordered by median using word_med_order
  box_scottishpolitics_karma <- ggplot(all_scottishpolitics_data, aes(x = word_med_order, y = utterance_score, fill = type)) +
    geom_boxplot(color = "black") +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(base = 10)) +
    ggtitle("Subreddit: r/scottishpolitics") +
    xlab("Hedge/Booster") +
    ylab("Karma Score (log10)") +
    coord_flip() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
  
  # Z-score boxplot, ordered by median using word_med_order_z
  box_scottishpolitics_z <- ggplot(all_scottishpolitics_data, aes(x = word_med_order_z, y = z_score, fill = type)) +
    geom_boxplot(color = "black") +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(base = 10)) +
    ggtitle("Subreddit: r/scottishpolitics") +
    xlab("Hedge/Booster") +
    ylab("Z-Score (log10)") +
    coord_flip() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
```

##### Resulting (correct) plots

[Karma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bn23.jpg)

[Z-score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G80JR.jpg)

Comment: Make sure your data is not grouped, as that will upset the reordering process (it will do it for each group, rather than overall)

Comment: I tried ungrouping, but it doesn't seem to work. Results are still the same with the following code:

```
  hedges_scottishpolitics_data <<- hedges_scottishpolitics_data %>% ungroup() %>%
    mutate(group = fct_reorder(unique_word, utterance_score, median))
  box_scottishpolitics_karma <<- ggplot(hedges_scottishpolitics_data,
                                        aes(x = unique_word, y=utterance_score, fill = unique_word)) + ...
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: I have never used dput, so I'm not quite sure if I am doing it correctly. [This is what the data looks like for reference](https://imgur.com/LKQDmco). The original data does not have the 'group' column though. That is added by the code.

dput() prints [this](https://pastebin.com/a4bsw1Kb).

Comment: I'm not sure what your `mutate` is for. You just need `hedges_scottishpolitics_data <- hedges_scottishpolitics_data %>% ungroup()` to ungroup it, and then use the code you have in your question.

Comment: Ah I see, my bad. When I do that the results are the same still sadly. It always sorts them in reverse alphabetical order.

Comment: It is possible that the `y` axis transform is confusing it. Try reordering it outside of `ggplot` - e.g. something like `h_s_d <- h_s_d %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(word2 = fct_reorder(unique_word, utterance_score))`, and then use `aes(x = word2, ...)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. When I do it outside of the ggplot call it still produces the same graph. I also tried simply removing the `y` axis transformation as well with and without ungrouping but this also didn't change anything sadly.

Comment: I see you are using two datasets. You probably need to apply the `fct_reorder` to both of them. Even better, combine them, do the reordering on the combined dataset, and use a single `geom_boxplot` with a `fill` aesthetic based on whether each entry is from `hedges` or `boosters`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I really appreciate your help. I will try this when I get the chance, but that seems like the way to do it. I'll get back to here when I've tried it.

Comment: @AndrewGustar I finally got around to doing it! Thanks so much for your help!!! I have edited my post with the new code.